# B2C - Custom Policy - Claim Type with Regex Restriction - Help Text not being displayed

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, aad-b2c

I want to restrict the first and last name to be Latin characters only.  So I added the following

```
      <ClaimType Id="givenName">
        <UserHelpText>First name must be in English.</UserHelpText>
        <Restriction>
          <Pattern RegularExpression="^[\u0020-\u007E\u00A0-\u00FF]*$" HelpText="First name must be in English." />
        </Restriction>
      </ClaimType>
```

The problem is when the user signs up and enters non-Latin characters, the message being displayed  is "Please match the requested format: Your first name".  I have not defined this message in my policy.

Is there any other attribute in the XML where I can define the message I would like to display ("First name must be in English.")

Answer (score 0):

this is a default message. It should only allow Latin characters by default. If needed you can change the [claim type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/261592/azure-ad-b2c-always-display-34please-match-the-for.html). You should also use [Localization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/localization) if you anticipate users to input non-Latin characters.